# How could I convert an image file to an ASCII image using C++?

Tags: c++, image, ascii

I am fairly new to programming and I would like to be able to convert an image, using C++, to an ASCII image. Help Please!

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do, and what part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  THis is not a good forum for these types of broad questions.  Please read the help on the site.

Comment: And why do you want to invent it yourself, with C++, instead of using one of the available tools, and then on the other hand you don't want to invent it and ask here how to do it?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you should probably google "ascii art c++ source code".

Answer (score 2):

Don't bully minors, guys. :-)

Declare "pixel brightness->char" mapping, iterate through every pixel of the image and print character based on the mapping.

```
for(int y=0; y<height; y++) {
    for( int x=0; x<width; x++ ) {
        std::cout << getCharacterByBrightness( getPixelBrightness(x,y) );
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The simplest mapping:

```
char getCharacterByBrightness( int brightness )
{
    if( brightness >= 128 )
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: One char per pixel would be a bit big, but luckily JPEG compresses pixels in 8x8 blocks. And it explicitly stores the average brightness of that block.